# save image to http server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Get an image from a http server. Resize the image to a thumnail and save back to the same folder as a different name "thumb" + imgName.
This all works apart from saving to the server again. I tried saving to local and it works so the server is the problem

```
    Image fullsizeImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(ResolveUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"] + exportedFileName))));
    Image thumbImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(newWidth, newHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
 thumbImage.Save(Server.MapPath(ResolveUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"] + "thumb_" + exportedFileName)));
```

This wont allow me to thumbImage.Save() back to the external server http it flags as `'http:/localhost:61318/Uploads/thumb_6086Jellyfish.jpg' is not a valid virtual path.`

So I need to pass it to a memory stream first?? I tried

```
string destinationFileName = ResolveUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"] + "thumb_" + exportedFileName);
 System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Open(destinationFileName, FileMode.Create);
thumbImage.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 fs.Close();
 //BUT THIS FLAGGED AS - uri formats are not supported
```

So Do I need to creat the memory first? then save the image to that path...any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WebImage helper for this kind of work. It's easier than implenting it by hand.

```
var photo = WebImage.GetImageFromRequest();
if(photo != null){
  var imagePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"] + exportedFileName;
  photo.Save(@"~\" + imagePath);

  //Let's save also a thumbnail
  var imageThumbPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesFolder"] + @"thumbs\" + exportedFileName;
  photo.Resize(width: 60, height: 60, preserveAspectRatio: true, preventEnlarge: true);
  photo.Save(@"~\" + imageThumbPath);
}
```

You just need to make sure the ImagesFolder app setting is a **virtual path** of your web application. Thus letting .NET decide where to physically store it on your server.

You can find a complete tutorial, with thumbnail saving, here:
http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/ui,-layouts,-and-themes/9-working-with-images